# How can we rewrite a url using htacess?

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to change the url 'http://www.xxxx.com/en/index.php/publisher/dashboardadvtsr' to 'advertiser.xxxx.com/dashboard'.How to use htacess rewrite method for this?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^xxxx.com/dashboard
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.xxxx.com/en/index.php/publisher/dashboardadvtsr
```

I tried this code in htacess, but it didn't work.Anybody please help me with a suitable solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this rule as very first rule in root .htaccess of `advertiser` site:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^advertiser\.(xxxx\.com)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^dashboard/?$ http://www.%1/en/index.php/publisher/dashboardadvtsr [L,NC,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's something like this instead...

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond $1 ^dashboard$
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.example.com/en/index.php/publisher/dashboardadvtsr [L,R=301]
```

I'm not sure why you need to match HTTP_HOST if you're writing this in .htaccess file (which already resolves virtual host to the corresponding DocumentRoot folder)